# java, setting -XX:HeapDumpPath directory to user.home

Tags: java, heap-dump

I'm trying to control where where my heap dumps go on out of memory exceptions using `-XX:HeapDumpPath`

My java process doesn't have permission to write to the current working directory, so I'm trying to specify the `user.home` directory.  I can't know the absolute name in advance, so I'm trying to do it using variable like `user.home`

I tried `-XX:HeapDumpPath=${user.home}/mydump.hprof`, but that doesn't work

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the command you propose, the `${user.home}` gets expanded by your shell before `java` is run, and will most likely be blank.

Change `${user.home}` to `${HOME}`.